# How do I do each normalization stage?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I have a database to create with a list of fields I need to include in it. I am required to do a table showing the normalization process from 1NF to 2NF to 3NF. However, I don't understand normalization AT ALL and I urgently need to try and get it normalized. The fields I am using are as follows:

**CustomerID**

Surname

Forename

Email

PhoneNo

**ReservationID**

DateRes

Collected(Y/N)

**PhoneID**

Brand

Model

OperatingSystem

ScreenSize

StorageSize

Price

Description

Img1

Img2

Thumbnail

Stock

Flagged (Y/N)

**ContactID**

Subject

Message

DateContact

Replied (Y/N)

I am not so good at database design so any help would be useful.

Comment: first you have to understand normalisation. 3NF is not difficult, even 4NF not. there is no way arround

Comment: @AlexWien The problem I'm finding is that some of the explanations seem really technical and I find it quite hard to grasp as well as the fact that any examples I see are not related to the sort of database I am going to be building

Comment: Up to the 4th normal form there are good examples available. for 5NF and 6NF which i never realy understood i have never seen examples. just search more

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not homework, I wonder why you have to show the process by which your reach 3NF at all.  If your database is in 3NF, who cares how you got there?  Again, assuming this is not homework, there is an easy way to design a database that is in 3NF right off the bat.

Learn ER modeling.  Use ER modeling to describe the information requirements your database has to meet.  Choose your entities carefully.  For each entity, choose an id for that entity very carefully.  If it's not in the data as given, you may have to synthesize an id.  This is data analysis, NOT database design.  Make very, very sure that the attributes you discover at this stage are attached to the correct entity or relationship.

This is context dependent.  For example, in a personnel system, "Date of Birth" is an attribute of an employee.  But in a birthing center, "Date of Birth" is an attribute of a birth, and the person born has a relationship to that birth.  Several persons can be born in one birth.

Learn how to convert an ER model to a relational model.  For these purposes SQL models and relational models can be treated as equivalent.  Be very, very careful in your choices of primary keys, and be aware of the consequences of using features like "automunber".  You may need to use this feature, but come up with ways of coping when redundant data entry results in two rows with different primary keys that both refer to the same instance of a subject matter entity.

If your attributes have been connected to the right entity or relationship, if you did the conversion to a relational model correctly, and if you chose your primary keys right, your database will automagically be in 3NF.

If this IS homework, then your teacher's requirements are not clear from your question.  It's probably just as easy to learn what the teacher is trying to teach you as it is to tell us what the real requirements are.

Comment: It's a database for a university project for a mobile phone site. Has requirements such as displaying mobile phones in the catalog, display details about each product, view phones based on category, search for products based on name/price, sort products by price, send a query to the site using a feedback form, reserve a phone for collection for up to 24H (Just reserve, not buy). I am asked to show a normalization table showing the attributes and entities in UNF, 1NF, 2NF and 3NF in separate columns as well as drawing an entity relationship diagram.

Comment: Again, why do they want to know this? It's a really strange user or client who would make this demand.  All you should have to prove to a regular client is that every column is either part of the table's key, or is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key (so help you Codd).